# Reference or Copy

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started with Python 3. In a Python book i read that the interpreter can be forced to make a copy of a instance instead creating a reference by useing the slicing-notation.

This should create a reference to the existing instance of s1:

```
s1 = "Test"
s2 = s1
print(s1 == s2)
print(s1 is s2)
```

This should create a new instance:

```
s1 = "Test"
s2 = s1[:]
print(s1 == s2)
print(s1 is s2)
```

When running the samples above both return the same result, a reference to s1.
Can sombody explain why it's not working like described in the book? Is it a error of mine, or a error in the book?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is true for *mutable* datatypes such as lists (i.e. works as you expect with `s1 = [1,2,3]`).

However strings and also e.g. tuples in python are immutable (meaning they cant be changed, you can only create new instances). There is no reason for a python interpreter to create copies of such objects, as you can not influence s2 via s1 or vice versa, you can only let s1 or s2 point to a different string.

Answer (score 2):

Since strings are immutable, there's no great distinction between a copy of a string and a new reference to a string. The ability to create a copy of a *list* is important, because lists are mutable, and you might want to change one list without changing the other. But it's impossible to change a string, so there's nothing to be gained by making a copy.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable in Python. It means, that once a string is created and is written to the memory, it could not be modified at all. Every time you "modify" a string, a new copy is created.
You may notice another interesting behaviour of CPython:

```
s1 = 'Test'
s2 = 'Test'
id(s1) == id(s2)
>>> True
```

As you can see, in CPython s1 and s2 refer to the same address in the memory.

If you need a full copy of a *mutable* object (e.g. a list), check the `copy` module from the standard library. E.g.

```
import copy

l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = l1
id(l2) == id(l1) # a reference
>>> True

l3 = copy.deepcopy(l1)
id(l3) == id(l1)
>>> False
```

Answer (score 1):

The slice-as-copy give you a new copy of the object only if it's applied to a **list**:

```
>>> t = ()
>>> t is t[:]
True
>>> l = []
>>> l is l[:]
False
>>> s = ''
>>> s is s[:]
True
```

There was already some discussion in the [python-dev mailing list](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2008-May/079689.html) of a way to make slice-as-copy work with strings but the feature was rejected due to performance issues.

Comment: This has nothing to do with slicing for strings and is just a fundamental part of how strings work. Python re-uses string objects all over the place. It is an optimization that does not affect properly-written user code.